# using findviewbyid in a class that does NOT extend Activity in android

Tags: android, class, android-activity, findviewbyid

I have a class that is currently extending Activity and I have methods like findViewById, ArrayAdapter etc.
I want to turn it into an independent class but all the above methods become undefined. What is the problem? Shouldn't importing the classes be enough? For eg, I import android.view.View for findViewById but it still makes no difference.
Please advise.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

you should pass the instance of your Activity to your Second Class on the constructor like this :

In your `Activity` Instanciate your Class like this :

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass(this);
```

And in your second Class , the **constructor** will be like this :

```
public class MyClass {

public Activity activity; 
//.... other attributes 

public MyClass( Activity _activity){

   this.activity = _activity;
//other initializations...

}
}
```

and then when you want to use the `findViewById()` method , you can do like this :

```
EditText txt = (EditText)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

Comment: This does not work. findViewById can only be called on Activity and not on Context. I tried your approach but it still gave me errors.

Comment: So see my edit, just pass the instance of the Activity intstead of the Context :)

Comment: Ok, I did that :) When I call findViewById on the Activity object, the Listiew that I'm trying to find is NULL. Is that because I haven't used setContentView for the XML file that contains the ListView, before?

Comment: Yes setContentView was missing and that was that problem. setContentView can be called on the Activity object.

Comment: yes that's it , when you override the method onCreate , you should always set the contentView BEFORE ANY call of the method findViewById() :)

Comment: @Houcine what should be done to make this work in AsyncTask as it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: you can create your own asynctask class wich extends from the asyncTask class. and then define a constructor to your class which takes the Activity context as parameter

Comment: The "problem" with this approach is that if you also need a reference from the activity to the class, it will create a circular dependency. Java can handle it, but not so sure if you would consider this a good practise. It introduces a risk for a memory leak here. For my use case I worked my way around it by re-defining my view inheritance hierarchy that fits the needs of my app.

Comment: Don't forget that it's often a bad idea to give away your activity. You make yourself open to bad encapsulation and memory leaks. Preferrably use a WeakReference

Comment: After I tried this, I was wondering why some data will not be stored to my firebase database anymore. I debugged at another point where it still worked. I was confused when I saw that Android Studio stopped at the breakpoints before storing the data, but firebase showed that the data was stored. At other points, it was not working anymore. I fixed this bug by deinstall the app once. I would not recommend this solution.

Answer (score 11):

if you want to call any function that belongs to `Activity` then only thing you need to have is context of the `Activity`.

eg.

```
class A extends Activity {
    Context ctx;

    void onCreate(Bundle b)
        ctx = this;
        B bob = new B(ctx);
    }
}
```

Here is class B.

```
class B {

    B (Activity a) {
        a.anyFunctionOfActivity();
    }
}
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky same here. What should be done to make this work in AsyncTask?

Answer (score 6):

[findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) is non-static public method of the `Activity` Class ,so it only be available for a `Activity` **object**. Therefore, import `android.view.View` and `android.app.Activity` won't make it available. To make it available, you could pass around a `Actvity` object - usually a `this`  point in your activity.  However, notice that you should always update your View in the UI thread.

Comment: Ok i understand why it's not available but isn't findViewById a method of the View class? Also could you explain why we should always update our View in the UI thread(are you referring to the main Activity?)?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
public static View getLayoutByRes(@LayoutRes int layoutRes,@Nullable ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    final LayoutInflater factory = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return factory.inflate(layoutRes, viewGroup);
}

TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutByRes(R.layout.xxx ,Null).findViewById(R.id.editd);
```

Comment: Where is getSystemService coming from?